# Get dashicon to align vertically with text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dashicons

I am using the [dashicons](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#cloud) which are built into wordpress.

Whenever I am using an icon in front or after a text, they are out of alignment. How would I make it, so that the icon aligns with the text?

I could change the HTML to make it a separate element, but preferentially looking for a css solution only, using the "before" selector.

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fullscreen:before {
    font-family: "dashicons";
    content: "\f211 ";
    font-size:20px;
}

<a class="fullscreen" href="#">FULL SCREEN</a>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh435h3y/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use inline-block and middle alignment on your icon `:before`. Example:

```
.fullscreen:before {
  font-family: "dashicons";
  content: "\f211 ";
  font-size:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh435h3y/1/)

Comment: Thank you. I used vertical-align before but without any luck. display:inline-block did the trick :)

Comment: Hi. I tried this on my page: https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/support-forums/ and the don't align. I took the styling back out. Any advice? Thanks.